# wm_copydata, stack around variable endpaint_text was corrupted

Tags: c++, winapi

I hooked Winapi EndPaint() function bellow and inside of it i am sending some wm_copydata but in the meantime on ocassion i am getting "wm_copydata, stack around variable endpaint_text was corrupted..." crash of the hooked App.

BOOL WINAPI Mine_EndPaint(HWND hWnd, const PAINTSTRUCT *lpPaint)
    {

```
    BOOL result = fpEndPaint(hWnd, lpPaint);

    if (hWnd == g_win)
    {

        if (lpPaint->rcPaint.left == g_12x && lpPaint->rcPaint.top == g_12y)
        {
        painting = 0;

        wchar_t endpaint_text[MAX_PATH] = L"deleting_a";
         COPYDATASTRUCT cds;
        ::ZeroMemory(&cds, sizeof(COPYDATASTRUCT));
        cds.cbData = sizeof(paint_dc);
        cds.lpData = endpaint_text;

        ::SendMessageTimeoutW(g_main, WM_COPYDATA, (WPARAM)::GetDesktopWindow(), (LPARAM)&cds, SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 1000, 0);

        }
        else if (lpPaint->rcPaint.left == g_list12x && lpPaint->rcPaint.top == 137)
        {

        big_painting = 0;
        wchar_t endpaint_text[MAX_PATH] = L"deleting_b";
         COPYDATASTRUCT cds;
        ::ZeroMemory(&cds, sizeof(COPYDATASTRUCT));
        cds.cbData = sizeof(paint_dc);
        cds.lpData = endpaint_text;

        ::SendMessageTimeoutW(g_main, WM_COPYDATA, (WPARAM)::GetDesktopWindow(), (LPARAM)&cds, SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 1000, 0);

        }
    }

    else if (check_d)
    {
        re_window = NULL;

        GetWindowText(hWnd, window_text, MAX_PATH);
        if (!wcscmp(window_text, L"Text"))
        {
            check_d = false;
            re_window = hWnd;
            wchar_t re_info[MAX_PATH] = L"";
            //wcscat(re_info, text);
            COPYDATASTRUCT cds;
            ::ZeroMemory(&cds, sizeof(COPYDATASTRUCT));
            cds.dwData = 931;
            cds.cbData = sizeof(re_info);
            cds.lpData = re_info;
            wsprintf(re_info, L"Text='%s', HWND='%X'", d_text, re_window);
            ::SendMessageTimeoutW(g_main, WM_COPYDATA, (WPARAM)::GetDesktopWindow(), (LPARAM)&cds, SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 1000, 0);

        }

    }
    return result;

}
```

Comment: Why are you setting cds.cbData to sizeof(paint_dc) ?

Answer (score 0):

It was overflowed wsprint, didnt have to do with anything about corrupted var mentioned.